# Variable not defined, when it is?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

So a bit of context is it pulls a local image link from firebase then it is supposed to set to the set image on page when clicking the marker, the image values work for the markers but set on a view outside the return doesn't work saying it is an undefined variable, also the console log shows the correct value as well. I removed all irrelevant parts of code to make it seem as easy to read as possible.

```js
export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      image: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView>
          {this.state.data.map((obj, index) => {
            return (
              <MapView.Marker
                key={index}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({ image: obj.image });
                  let { value } = 'require(' + obj.image + ')';
                  console.log(value);
                }}>
                <Image source={require(obj.image)} style={styles.pet} />
              </MapView.Marker>
            );
          })}
        </MapView>

        <View style={styles.petinfo}>
          <Image style={styles.locpetimg} source={value} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(HomeScreen);
```

Comment: Which variable is supposedly `undefined`? Where in your code is that error coming from?

Comment: what is this `this.state.data`? never see you declare or assign any array

Comment: The **value** variable returns undefined when trying to set the source image, everything else works fine. I removed irrelevant code because its quite a big component.

Comment: It's not advised to use arrow functions on events in the `render()` section. Every render it will create a new function.

Comment: Are you trying to use the "value" set with  "onPress" inside  <Image/> ?? thats not possible as its out of scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use the "value" set with  "onPress" inside  `<Image/>` ?? that's not possible as it's out of scope. try something like

```
export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.value = null;
    this.state = {
      image: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView>
          {this.state.data.map((obj, index) => {
            return (
              <MapView.Marker
                key={index}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({ image: obj.image });
                  this.value = 'require(' + obj.image + ')';
                  console.log(value);
                }}>
                <Image source={require(obj.image)} style={styles.pet} />
              </MapView.Marker>
            );
          })}
        </MapView>

        <View style={styles.petinfo}>
          <Image style={styles.locpetimg} source={this.value} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(HomeScreen);
```

Here I'm storing the value in a member variable of the class and then using it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      image: '',
      data:[]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView>
          {this.state.data.map((obj, index) => {
            return (
              <MapView.Marker
                key={index}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({ image: obj.image });
                  let { value } = 'require(' + obj.image + ')';
                  console.log(value);
                }}>
                <Image source={require(obj.image)} style={styles.pet} />
              </MapView.Marker>
            );
          })}
        </MapView>

        <View style={styles.petinfo}>
          <Image style={styles.locpetimg} source={value} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(HomeScreen);
```